# Worksheet.CodeName empty

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to reference newly added Worksheet by it's CodeName property. The problem is that CodeName returns empty string unless run from debugger.

```
Set tableSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
MsgBox tableSheet.CodeName
```

Even this simple example doesn't work unless I put a break point on MsgBox line.
What is the problem with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to duplicate your issue.  Some googling revealed this answer:

```
Sub test()
Dim tablesheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set tablesheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(tablesheet.Name).Properties("Codename")
End Sub
```

I think you have to check Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 in Tools>References.

Comment: I did it this way but this also has some limitations. This will not work if you already changed the name of the sheet. You must read the Codename property right after you created the new sheet. Otherwise, Excel will not be able to find the sheet using the new name.

Answer (score 2):

I also needed to read codename for new sheet. This solution worked for me:

1. Go to Trust Center, under Macro settings check "Trust access to VBA project model".
2. Now just put this three lines before the line where you need code name. It won't work without this. It is a VBA quirk.

```
On Error Resume Next
Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).CodeName).Properties("Codename")
On Error GoTo 0
```

3. Now use your code name like this:

```
strActiveSheetCodeName = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).CodeName).Properties("Codename")
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this behavior. I have never used `CodeName` before, I use sometimes `Name` to reference a sheet.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim tableSheet As New Worksheet

    Set tableSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    MsgBox tableSheet.Name
End Sub
```

This gives the name of the sheet in the `MsgBox` and it is not only readable, you can change the name of the sheet if you want.

Comment: The thing is that I need to reference sheets that I have created and don't want to use the name because user can change it through Excel GUI. I don't like to take away functionality from the user just because of some stupid bugs like this.

Comment: @bombardier Have you tried it only with MsgBox? I tried now `For Each s In Worksheets
        s.Range("A1") = s.CodeName
    Next s` and it seems to be working. Even when I change the sheet names the CodeName in `A1` is correct.

Comment: @stema This works. Somehow it doesn't work for worksheets created by VB code unless the VB Editor is started.

Comment: @bombardier, even `Set tableSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    tableSheet.Range("A1") = tableSheet.CodeName` is working without editor started. It seems to be only a problem together with MsgBox.

Comment: @stema This doesn't work for me. Maybe it is a version thing. I have Excel 2003 SP3.

Comment: @bombardier, I do have exactly the same Excel version. I am sorry I have no further idea at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem for a new sheet that created by macro (it would have a blank codename unless you open the Macro Editor).
For my case, since I need the code name to insert some macro to the new sheet. So I use the following code, and it works. It seems the codeName would have value, due to my code access Name attribute of 'VBComponents.item', which is codeName attribute for sheet.

Note: I am not sure why, below code would open the VBA Editor automatically.

```
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

Dim i
For i = 1 To VBProj.VBComponents.Count
    If VBProj.VBComponents.Item(i).Name = ActiveSheet.CodeName Then
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents.Item(i)
    End If
Next
```